# How many degrees of separation between 2 vertices on a Delaunay Triangulation

Tags: python, scipy, voronoi, delaunay

I've made a Voronoi Diagram using the `scipy.spatial` Python library of a set of LatLon points to find the Neighbors of each points. Then, I found that a Delaunay  Triangulation would be more useful, and now I can easily find the "first tier" and the "second tier" Neighbors of each point, using the this algorithm:

```
def findNeighbors(delaunay):
    "Returns a adjacency list of the graph"
    neighbors = defaultdict(set)

    for simplex in delaunay.simplices:
        for vertice in simplex:
            other = set(simplex)
            other.remove(vertice)
            neighbors[vertice] = neighbors[vertice].union(other)
    return neighbors

def neighborCount(graph, start, target):
    if target in graph[start]:
        return 'First Tier Neighbor'
    elif graph[start] & graph[target]:
        return 'Second Tier Neighbor'
```

But the problem is that I need to find up to the "6th tier neighbor", and I cant find a way to do that without looping through all of the adjacency list. Here is an example of a "3rd Tier Neighbor" that I want to find.

[image]

Is there a more clever way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found that an Breadth First Search or a Depth First Search algorithm can do that, but they also return the path, and I don't need this, so, I made a function that only returns the lenght of the path, making it way more faster.

```
def getNeighbor(neighbors, graph):
    out = set()
    for neighbor in neighbors:
        out = out.union(graph[neighbor])
    return out 


def tier_count(graph, start, target):

    if target in graph[start]:
        return "1 tier"

    else:  
        visited = set()
        queue = getNeighbor(graph[start], graph)
        count = 2
    
        while queue:
            if target in queue:
                return str(count) + " Tier"
        
            else:
                count += 1
                visited = visited.union(queue)
                queue = getNeighbor(queue, graph) - visited
            
    return "No tiers between these cells"
```